# Add or Remove multiple language support in Android

Tags: android, xml, localization

Suppose app provides multi-language support for example English and French.
And it has 2 different folders for `string.xml` as per standard android guidelines to support different language.

```
res/values/strings.xml
res/values-fr/strings.xml
```

Can I exclude any specific XML (for example in this case, values-fr) folder from App build? Meaning when an APK of this app is generated, it should not contain support for `values-fr`. Also, later, if I need to add the same, where to make the change to include `values-fr`?

What build properties app needs to configure to support this "dynamic" add/remove of multi-language support?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013904/disable-localization-in-android-application

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, then see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28296298/1893766)